# How can I use setw() with input stream

Tags: c++, setw

I know some people will say this question is repeated but I really couldn't find a useful answer.

Let's say I have the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cout;

int main(){
    std::string something;
    cout<<"Type something";
    std::cin>>something;
}
```

How can I use `setw()` so the output will look like this?

```
Type something "then after some whitespaces for example 10 the user will start typing"
```

I tried to use `setw()` in output:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <iomanip>
 using std::cout;

 int main(){
    std::string something;
    cout<<std::left<<std::setw(24)<<"Type something";
    std::cin>>something;
}
```

The expected output was supposed to be:

[image]

The actual output is:

[image]

Comment: Use `setw` on your output, not your input.

Comment: @NathanOliver I tried using  cout<<std::left<<std::setw(24)<<"Type something"; but still the same problem the user input starts after Type something directly

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. The code you've shown so far shows no use of `setw`. It doesn't even include `iomanip`.

Comment: @Chris I edited the code you can see it now

Comment: @Chris Here I tried to use it in output but it didn't work when I tried with input I got the same output

Comment: Can you provide a sample of expected vs. actual output?

Comment: @Chris check it now please

Comment: It's funny, because when I try this, I get the expected outcome. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @Seba [Can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/eNN8T6), the code you showed works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce what you say, the code you have showed [works fine for me](https://ideone.com/eNN8T6).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

int main(){
    std::string something;
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(24) << "Type something"; // prints "Type something          "
    std::cin >> something;
    return 0;
}
```

That said, you could simply output a string with the desired number of spaces:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string something;
    std::cout << "Type something          ";
    // alternatively:
    // std::cout << "Type something" << std::string(10, ' ');
    std::cin >> something;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information but still when I run the code the user input starts directly after the printed messege if I use  std::string(10,' ')

Comment: I want the user to start typing after a specific amount of whitespace and it's inefficient to just use spaces in cout statement if I need a large number of whitespaces

Comment: @Seba what you claim is physically impossible given the code shown. So you must be doing something different than what you showed.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution might be using any special character after `setw`

Sample Code:

```
int main()
{
    std::string something;
    cout<< "Type something" << setw(24) << ":";
    std::cin>>something;
}
```

Output:

`Type something                       :inputString`

References:

[iomanip setw() function in C++ with Examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iomanip-setw-function-in-c-with-examples/)

[Setw C++: An Ultimate Guide to Setw Function](https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/cpp-tutorial/setw-cpp)

Comment: The want space between `Type something` and the input they enter.  This wont do that.